# Loop through mysqli results array once to get all information

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I am querying the database for data, but in order to do what I need, I end up looping through that results array at least three times. How do I get all of the info I need out of the array without having to loop so many times? I need to get data from the array based on the results from the previous loops. The code below is the only way I could figure out in order to only query the database once.

```
$recordSQL = mysqli_query($link, $sqlString);
$resultMonths = array();
while($recordResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recordSQL)) $resultMonths[] = $recordResult['date'];
mysqli_data_seek($recordSQL, 0);
$uniqueMonths = array_unique($resultMonths);
foreach($uniqueMonths as $key => $date){
    echo '</div><div class="current-month">'.translateDate($date, '').'</div>';
    $resultCompanies = array();
    while($companyResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recordSQL)){
        if($companyResult['date'] == $date) $resultCompanies[] = $companyResult['company'];
    }
    mysqli_data_seek($recordSQL, 0);
    $uniqueCompanies = array_unique($resultCompanies);
    $oldco = '';
    foreach($uniqueCompanies as $key => $company){
        $x = 0;
        while($typeResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recordSQL)){
            if($typeResult['date'] == $date && $typeResult['company'] == $company){
                if($oldco != $typeResult['company']){
                    if($x != 0) echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="company-record">'.$typeResult['name'].' - ';
                }
                if($x > 0) echo ', ';
                echo translateID('Type', $typeResult['type']).'('.translateID('Section', $typeResult['section']).')';
                $oldco = $typeResult['company'];
                $x++;
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';
        mysqli_data_seek($recordSQL, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, you are actually looping N**3 times. Do it this way:

```
$month_company_rows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recordSQL)) {
    $month_company_rows[$row['date']][$row['company']][] = $row;
}

foreach ($month_company_rows as $date => $company_rows) {
    echo '</div><div class="current-month">'.translateDate($date, '').'</div>';

    foreach ($company_rows as $company => $rows) {
        echo '<div class="company-record">'.$company.' - ';

        foreach ($rows as $x => $row) {
            if($x > 0) echo ', ';
            echo translateID('Type', $row['type']).'('.translateID('Section', $row['section']).')';
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```